# Downloads never start

Tags: downloads

I have tried to download several times from the download page and it never starts, just hangs. The download "now" link is http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=lts.

Is there any other location I can use?

Answer (score 1):

put this link in your browser http://ubuntu-releases.mirror.net.in/releases//precise/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso your download will automatically starts.
OR

Download `flareget` download manager from [**here**](http://flareget.com/download).Put the above mentioned link in the `flareget->Add URL` option and click start,your download will starts.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is odd. It is only google-chrome that won't download. I thought to try Firefox and it is working fine.

(the link above did not work either - same symptom; just hangs)